# Javascript - Trying to use a switch statement

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to using switches in HTML with javascript. I am trying to make a text enlarger program where the text can enlarge or become smaller depending on what the user selects. Currently when you click on either of the buttons, nothing happens. I'm not sure how to get the switch to work. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Changing the size of the text </title>
    <script>
    switch resize(size) {
    case S:
        if (document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize == "") {
                document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize = "1.0em";
        break;
        }
    case L:
        if (document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize == "") {
                document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize = "-1.0em";
        break;
        }
    default:
        document.body.style.fontSize = "";
    }

    document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize = parseFloat    (document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize) + (size * 0.1) + "em";
    </script>
        </head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="resize(1);">A+</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="resize(-1);">A-</a>
<p id="change">Text Size Change!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read the error message(s). That is invalid syntax .. and has several semantic errors.

Comment: What does S and L mean? What is your console telling you?

Comment: go through some basic javascript tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using variables instead of strings, maybe thats the issue,
try changing the following lines:

```
case S:
case L:
```

To

```
case 'S':
case 'L':
```

Or declare variables S and L with the needed values.

and it should be

```
switch (size) {
```

instead of

```
switch resize(size) {
```

Also, the break should be outside the IF curly braces.

Comment: You should at least paste the error/warning you are getting.

Comment: there is no error or warning, when I try to enlarge the text in browser, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn some basics. But for now you can try this ,

This just increases once then decreases once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Changing the size of the text </title>
    <script>
    function resize(size) {
      if(document.getElementById("change") && document.getElementById("change").style) {
      switch (size) {
        case 'L':
          document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize = "2.0em";
          break;
        case 'S':   
          document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize = "1.0em";
          break;
        default:
          document.body.style.fontSize = "";
        }
      }
    }

    </script>
        </head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="resize('L');">A+</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="resize('S');">A-</a>
<p id="change">Text Size Change!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is for if you want to continuously keep on increasing or decreasing font size

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title> Changing the size of the text </title>
        <script>
          document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize = "20px";
        function resize(size) {
          if(document.getElementById("change") && document.getElementById("change").style) {
          var fontSize = document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize;
          var fontValue = Number(fontSize.substring(0, fontSize.length-2));
          var changeInPx = 4;
          switch (size) {
            case 'L':
              document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize = (fontValue+changeInPx)+"px";
              break;
            case 'S':   
              document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize = (fontValue-changeInPx)+"px";
              break;
            default:
              document.body.style.fontSize = "";
            }
          }
        }

        </script>
            </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="resize('L');">A+</a> 
    <a href="#" onclick="resize('S');">A-</a>
    <p id="change">Text Size Change!</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Check the update now. I had assumed you wanted increase and decrease of font size only once. The new code has a continuous increment and decrement font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the resize function, not use it directly in the switch case

breaks shouldn't be in "if" statements

Here is a working demo : http://fiddle.jshell.net/L57hee8v/1/

Answer (score 0):

The whole logic behind it should be changed. Here is a working example.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/p131ukz9/)

```js
var ch = $('#change');
var changeAmount = 8;
/*Resized the change element based by changeAmount*/
function resizeMe(size) {
    ch.css('font-size', parseInt(ch.css('font-size')) + (size * changeAmount) + "px");
}
/*binds the click event to every `a` */
$('a').click(function () {
    resizeMe($(this).data('size'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-size='1'>A+</a> 
<a href="#" data-size='-1'>A-</a>

<p id="change">Text Size Change!</p>
```